# How to subset sample satisfy conditions throughout the entire sample period?

Tags: r

```
 firm   year   rating
 A      2010   1
 A      2011   1
 A      2012   1
 B      2010   1
 B      2011   1
 C      2010   1
 C      2011   2
 C      2012   2
```

I want to subset firms satisfy the following conditions.

1. Firms do not change their ratings throughout the entire period, so that firm C does not satisfy because it changed rating from 1 to 2.
2. Each firm contains at least one observation both before and after 2011, so that firm B does not satisfy because it has no observation after 2011.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

```
# load the 'data.table' package
library(data.table)

# convert your dataframe to a data.table
setDT(df)

# filter
df[, if(any(year < 2011) & any(year > 2011) & uniqueN(rating) == 1) .SD, by = firm]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    firm year rating
> 1:    A 2010      1
> 2:    A 2011      1
> 3:    A 2012      1
> ```

---

The same idea implemented in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(firm) %>% 
  filter(any(year < 2011) & any(year > 2011) & n_distinct(rating) == 1)
```

---

Or in base R:

```
i1 <- as.logical(with(df, ave(year, firm, FUN = function(x) any(x < 2011) & any(x > 2011))))
i2 <- as.logical(with(df, ave(rating, firm, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1)))

df[i1 & i2, ]
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Jaap, how to do in base R and dplyr if I need `rating == "AAA" , "AA" , "BB" , and "BBB"`

Comment: @1412MM I guess you need `rating %in% c("AAA" , "AA" , "BB" , "BBB")`